# Custom export option for report

Tags: reporting, custom-object, custom-button

We are trying to allow users to narrow down items on a report based on whatever criteria they want(they are looking for specific phone numbers to call for the day). Once they do this we are looking for a way to either

a) push the report data to a new custom object collection which will allow a third party SOQL Query to pull this data and begin the dialing process

b) Write a custom export option to push the report data to a third party application to begin the dialing process

c) Custom button on a report to push the data from the report.

Any of these options is possible, if none of them are possible i would be curious what anyone thinks a valid solution to this would be.

I have thought about creating a custom view with a button to push them, but the customer is really looking for a single report with the options to narrow down. Any help would be appreciated.